# Can node express serve the next request before returning a response for the current request?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm wondering if nodejs needs to finish returning a response for the current request before serving the next one. I couldn't find the answer for my question anywhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it process next one using callback.

Comment: @eduPeeth there can be multiple scenarios , in one of the scenarios I have explained the condition in question will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs is called single threaded because all the requests are served by a single thread(let's call this thread main).

Lets say your two requests are coming in the server:
Request 1 -> Has to read a large file (let's say about 100MB) and then parse a result and then return the value
Request 2 -> fetch the result of 2+2 and then return a response

From the requests we can see that Request 1 will take a lot of time while Request 2 won't.

If you have written the code correctly i.e. using asynchronous programming Request1 will be processed by another thread than main, then if Request2 comes it will get a response before Request1.

If not written proper code , Request2 won't be processed till Request1's processing is completed.

I hope this answers your question.